# From algebraic symbols to symbolic functions

Tags: functions, symbolic, built-in-symbols

i have a code which gives an output of this kind:

```
rrr=2*f+1;
```

Now i define a simple function:

```
f[x_]:=3*x+2;
```

1. How should i do if i want the variable `f` **to be replaced by the function** `f[x_]` ?
2. If i want to do the **inverse process**: from the function `f[x_]` to `f` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rrr2 = rrr /. f -> f[x]
```

> 1 + 2 (2 + 3 x)

```
rrr2 /. f[x] -> f
```

> 1 + 2 f

Comment: ah yes using conditions, i did not try in this way. Thanks

Comment: @siderius -- these are not "conditions" --- the command /. is a short form of ReplaceAll, which is exactly what you are asking for, to replace f with f[x] or vice versa.